# Do WCF REST services support HTTP 301 redirects?

Tags: wcf, rest, http-status-code-301

Is it possible to implement a HTTP 301 redirect for a WCF REST Service so that URLs of the form:

> http://server/customers/?name=John

redirects to

> http://server/customers/324

(For the client-side case of this question, see [Does the WCF REST WebChannelFactory client support REST services that use redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033142/does-the-wcf-rest-webchannelfactory-client-support-rest-services-that-use-redirec))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure just set the location and the status code

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Location = "http://server/customers/324";
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
```

I don't know how the WCF client handles redirects, but it is relatively simple to do using HttpWebRequest.