# Does the WCF REST WebChannelFactory client support REST services that use redirects?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, client-side, webchannelfactory

If you have a RESTful web service that uses HTTP 301 redirects to send requests like:

> http://server/customers/?name=John

to the url

> http://server/customers/324

(as created by a service similar to the one in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032937/do-wcf-rest-services-support-http-301-redirects))

Can these types of services be consumed with the WebChannelFactory and a ServiceContract? If so, how?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to use the WebChannelFactory stuff?  .Net has some great libraries for accessing http based services.  Why not use those?

Comment: @Darrel: what libraries?

Comment: @Jacob: did you ever get this fixed? For that matter, did you ever try this? Your question doesn't say what you tried and what the results were.

Comment: @John: Nope, I ended up never needing this from the client side of things.

@Darrel: If you're talking about WebClient and its kin, that's one thing I seriously wanted to avoid (serializing and deserializing everythinh by hand? Meh.)

Since I'm in control of the actual REST services, and they are also implemented in WCF, WebChannelFactory was the logical zero-friction choice.